# With the Elimination of God Class "Mage::" can we say Magento is now Atheist

Tags: discussion, magento2

I was reading some articles about Magento 2.0 and came across one from [Amasty Blog](https://blog.amasty.com/magento-2-release-facts-and-rumors/). It is a very informative article. There i saw a point which states **God class “Mage::” is eliminated**

As soon as i read it a question popped up my mind, So now who will control the whole flow, Who can we pray for giving us the power of inheritance?

I am asking this question over here as we have many **Angels of Magento** over here who can provide pretty good information about it.

Please make the answer informative and funny too in this festive season.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will bow down to the all mighty Dependency Injection.
Here is preview: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/basics-dependency-injection-usage-magento-2/

Here is the full "holly book": http://devdocs.magento.com/

Comment: Thank you angel for spreading the message of GOD